# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically in Python 3 Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using AWS EMR with 16 core and 30 GIB RAM Pyspark server. I am using python3 kernel and running a program. After 80% completion, kernel is dying with the error **"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"**.

I'm not using tensorflow. I'm thinking that it is reading 620 MB dataframe which is generated during the process and joining with 2 MB dataframe.

```
df1=pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on=['col2','col2', 'col3','col4'],right_on=['col2','col2', 'col3','col4']).drop_duplicates()
```

Any ideas how can I reduce the load on RAM and solve the Kernel dying issue?